# How to call the index function inside a class when a file is load?

Tags: php

I'm wondering how I can call the index function inside the class `App`, an example:

the user put this URL in the browser: `www.application/controllers/application.php`

the file `application.php` contain this:

```
<?php 

    Class App{

         public function index()
         {
             // do stuff..
         }
   ...
```

I want that when this file is opened in the browser, the index function must be executed automatically... How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should go back a step and re-read about how MVC works. You confuse controller and action here. The action "index" is requested in a controller, the the class is the controller and in it a function `indexAction` is invoked.

Comment: but I can call index function now?

Comment: Read up on reflection in PHP. This should get ya started: http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call index on an instance of `App`.

```
$app = new App();
$app->index();
```

However, it feels like there is something missing here. Typically you would have a router that would handle instantiating the correct controller based on the route requested by the user.

You can use the above code to manually instantiate the app controller and call index, but again, I think there is a missing piece.

Comment: Okay. At this point the question is: there is an open source router that I can customize?

Comment: @SevengamesXoom Yes, lots. But you may want to take a look at an entire framework first. Laravel for example.

Comment: @SevengamesXoom Laravel is "pure php". If you mean you want to build something yourself, then I still think you should take a look at other frameworks as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate an object of class `App` and to invoke the `index` method directly:

```
<?php 

    Class App{

         public function index()
         {
             // do stuff..
         }
    }
   ...

    $app = new App();
    $app->index();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to *index* inside __construct() method

```
<?php 

  Class App{

     function __construct(){
        $this->index();
     }

     public function index()
     {
         // do stuff..
     }

     new App();
```

Then instantiate App();